# Predicting cutoff in python using scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

As I'm using python for the first time for data mining, I'm facing problems to tune the parameters and get the best parameter values (cutoff, classwt, sampsize). I'm trying to find the cutoff values for different classes using random forest in scikit learn. I'm using the following code

```
def cutoff_predict(rf,trainArr,cutoff):
   return (rf.predict_prob(trainArr)[:,1]>cutoff).astype(int)

score=[]
def custom_f1(cutoff):
    def f1_cutoff(rf,trainArr,y):
        ypred=cutoff_predict(rf,trainArr,cutoff)
        return sklearn.metrics.f1_score(Actualres,results)
    return f1_cutoff
for cutoff in np.arange(0.1,0.9,0.1):
    rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100) #Random forest generation for Classification
    rf.fit(trainArr, trainRes) #Fit the random forest model
validated=cross_val_score(rf,trainArr,trainRes,cv=10,scoring=custom_f1(cutoff))
    score.append(validated)
```

But I'm getting the following error.

```
    IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-f8b808ce9a4d> in <module>()
     94     rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100) #Random forest generation for Classification
     95     rf.fit(trainArr, trainRes) #Fit the random forest model
---> 96     validated=cross_val_score(rf,trainArr,trainRes,cv=10,scoring=custom_f1(cutoff))
     97     score.append(validated)

C:\Python27\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cross_validation.pyc in cross_val_score(estimator, X, y, scoring, cv, n_jobs, verbose, fit_params, pre_dispatch)
   1350     X, y = indexable(X, y)
   1351 
-> 1352     cv = _check_cv(cv, X, y, classifier=is_classifier(estimator))
   1353     scorer = check_scoring(estimator, scoring=scoring)
   1354     # We clone the estimator to make sure that all the folds are

C:\Python27\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cross_validation.pyc in _check_cv(cv, X, y, classifier, warn_mask)
   1604         if classifier:
   1605             if type_of_target(y) in ['binary', 'multiclass']:
-> 1606                 cv = StratifiedKFold(y, cv, indices=needs_indices)
   1607             else:
   1608                 cv = KFold(_num_samples(y), cv, indices=needs_indices)

C:\Python27\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cross_validation.pyc in __init__(self, y, n_folds, indices, shuffle, random_state)
    432         for test_fold_idx, per_label_splits in enumerate(zip(*per_label_cvs)):
    433             for label, (_, test_split) in zip(unique_labels, per_label_splits):
--> 434                 label_test_folds = test_folds[y == label]
    435                 # the test split can be too big because we used
    436                 # KFold(max(c, self.n_folds), self.n_folds) instead of

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

What could be the problem here? Also: In 'R' we have option to tune 'cutoff' parameter(cutoff = 1/(number of classes)). Is there a similar parameter in random forest(scikit learn package) to tune in python?

Comment: What error are you getting? Your post doesn't specify.

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI  sorry.. I updated the question.

Comment: Looks much better now :-)